# Xcode 11 project on MacOS not to use sin and cos in one function: undefined symbol "___sincosf_stret"

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang++, cmath

Building my libraries on Mac suddenly started to fail with Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29).

I was able to isolate one problem:

It seems that when you use sin and cos in the same function, the optimizer will use __sincosf_stret to calculate both at once.

So what did I do:

1. Create a new Xcode project, cmd line tool, objective-c
2. Change the main.m to main.mm to allow C++
3. Change main as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <cmath>

void coordinateCalculator(float angle, float radius, float& x, float& y) {
    float mySin = sin(angle);
    float myCos = cos(angle);
    x = radius * myCos;
    y = radius * mySin;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        float myAngle = 0.0;
        float theX, theY;
        float radius = 100.0;
        while (myAngle < 360.0) {
            coordinateCalculator(myAngle, radius, theX, theY);
            NSLog(@"My coordinates: %f, %f",theX,theY);
            myAngle += 1.0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Building in Debug works fine, building for profile (Release version with optimization) will fail giving the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sincosf_stret", referenced from:
      coordinateCalculator(float, float, float&, float&) in main.o
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm building with:

- C++: C++14, libC++
- Base SDK: MacOS
- Deployment target 10.14

When I change the deployment target to 10.7, the sincosf_stret is found, but I get 2 ARC errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_objc_loadClassref", referenced from:
      __ARCLite__load() in libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o)
  "_objc_readClassPair", referenced from:
      __ARCLite__load() in libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Playing with the deployment SDKs give me:

- 10.7: 2 ARC link errors
- 10.10: 2 ARC link errors AND _sincosf_ret error
- 10.12 or higher: _sincosf_ret error

I can't belief that it is not possible to use sin/cos in one function.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing XCode solved my issue. Another developer had tried it on his system and it seemed to work. That made me decide to delete XCode and install it again. Problem is gone now. No problem with XCode itself.